# What's wrong with my usage of add_filter

Tags: plugin-development

I wanted to override the wordpress default search with my custom search, however when i put the following code in the plugin file it doesn't appear replace the default searchbox(no error, nothing) and when i put the code in functions.php it works fine and replaces the default searchbox.

Can anyone tell me why is it not working in plugin file? Thanks!

```
function DynamiteSearch($form) {
    $form = '<form method="get" id="searchform" action="' . get_option('home') . '/" >
    <div><label class="hidden" for="s">' . __('Search for:') . '</label>
    <input type="text" value="' . attribute_escape(apply_filters('the_search_query', get_search_query())) . '" name="s" id="s" />
    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="'.attribute_escape(__('Search')).'" />
    </div>
    </form>';
    return $form;
}

add_filter('get_search_form', 'DynamiteSearch');
```

Comment: Are you sure the plugin is activated? If it is, it would help if you could post the entire plugin file.

Comment: My plugin only has this much of code with regular plugin header. I am able to activate the plugin as normally, no problem with that.

Answer (score 2):

I cleaned up your code, and put all the header information for installing it. Your plugin works fine, I tested it!

```
/*
Author: whoever
Plugin Name: Some Name
Plugin URI: 
Text Domain: some-domain
Version: 1.0
*/

function DynamiteSearch($form) 
{
    $form = "<form method = 'get' id = 'searchform' action = ' ".site_url()." ' >";
    $form .= "<div><label class = 'hidden' for='s'>". __("Search for: ") . "</label>";
    $form .= "<input type = 'text' value=' ". attribute_escape(apply_filters('the_search_query', get_search_query())) ." ' name='s' id='s' />";
    $form .= "<input type = 'submit' id='searchsubmit' value=' ".attribute_escape(__('Look for it'))." ' />";
    $form .= "</div>";
    $form .= "</form>";

    return $form;
}

add_filter('get_search_form', 'DynamiteSearch');
```

Try changing the submit button text to see if it works. Let me know if it worked for you.

Thanks,
Rutwick

Comment: Thanks Rutwick! But for some reason the searchbox on my site still doesn't change. Were you able to change the searchbox with this code? thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Yes Arvind... I tested it by changing the button text and it showed up well. I'm using 'TwentyTen' theme...

Comment: Are you using a caching Plugin, or a CDN, or any other form of caching that might be preventing you from seeing the modified output?

Answer (score 0):

If the code you've posted is literally all the code you're placing into the file, that'll be why.

Firstly you need plugin headers at the top of the file, eg..

```
/*
    Author: whoever
    Description: whatever
    Domain Path: /lang
    Plugin Name: Some Name
    Plugin URI: 
    Text Domain: some-domain
    Version: 1.0
*/
```

Secondly you need to activate the plugin from the plugins admin page(Admin > Plugins), but it'll only appear in that list once the plugin has a valid header, like the one posted above.

If neither of those two things is the problem, please post up more of your code(there must be more, because you're missing the plugin headers from what's posted)..

Hope that helps.. :)